# In the absence of a signal handler, does SIGTERM behave identically to SIGKILL?

Tags: process, signals

Most descriptions of SIGTERM and SIGKILL point out that SIGKILL,

> In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, [...] cannot be caught or ignored [...] ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal))

Is this the only difference between SIGTERM and SIGKILL? In particular, if a process does not install a SIGTERM handler, is there any difference at all between sending SIGTERM or SIGKILL to the process?

Comment: For clarity - programs don't need to "install" a signal handler, rather, they just choose to catch the signal (by implementing an appropriate function), or not (in which case, yes, sigterm = sigkill).

Comment: @taifwa there’s more to it than that, processes can ignore or pause a signal without catching it.

Answer (score 5):

In the absence of any signal configuration, `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL` are in practice equivalent, at least from the killed process’s perspective, as are the other signals whose default action is to terminate a process, including `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`. As [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu) points out, the parent process is informed of the signal which terminated the child process (which is how your shell can distinguish between the signals, and print *e.g.* “terminated” v. “user-defined signal 1”).

As mentioned on Wikipedia, `SIGKILL` can’t be caught or ignored, whereas `SIGTERM` can; note that this means that a process doesn’t need to install a handler for `SIGTERM` to be ineffective, it can simply block it or ignore it (see [`sighold()`, `sigrelse()` and `sigignore()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sighold.html)).

POSIX as a detailed section on the [rationale behind signal handling](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap02.html#tag_22_02_04). The Linux [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) manpage documents signals in detail too.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the only difference between SIGTERM and SIGKILL?

No.

A big difference between a `SIGKILL` and an uncaught `SIGTERM` is that the former will also *wake up* a stopped process (so it could immediately destroy itself), while the latter will only have effect after a `SIGCONT`.

Simple example:

```
$ sleep 1000 & sleep 1; kill -TSTP $!
[1] 6455

[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 1000
$ kill -TERM 6455
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 1000
$ kill -CONT 6455
$ jobs
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 1000
```

If you want to be sure that your `TERM`, `HUP`, `INT`, etc. signal has any effect, you should pair it with a `CONT` signal (in any order).

People may not readily get that because of the magic of the bash's `kill` builtin -- when used with a job id like `%` or `%1` (or with a negated pid) referring to a stopped *job*, it will [do all that itself](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c#n3670) behind the curtains:

```
/* Give PID SIGNAL.  This determines what job the pid belongs to (if any).
   If PID does belong to a job, and the job is stopped, then CONTinue the
   job after giving it SIGNAL.  Returns -1 on failure.  If GROUP is non-null,
   then kill the process group associated with PID. */
int
kill_pid (pid, sig, group)
```